# Return array in service in c++

Tags: c++, rosservice, ros-tutorials, msg, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people!
I'm starting with ROS and I have a problem implementing a client and server. I used the files created in the tutorials of ROS but I would like to return an array of strings and I don't know how to do it. These are my codes:

get_element_server.cpp:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/GetElement.h"

bool add(beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Request  &req,
         beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response &res)
{
  res.result = {"table", "chair"};
  ROS_INFO("request: x=%s", req.name.c_str());
  ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%s] [%s]", res.result[0].c_str(), res.result[1].c_str());
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_element_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("get_element", add);
  ROS_INFO("Ready to get element.");
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

get_element_client.cpp:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/GetElement.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_element_client");
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    ROS_INFO("usage: get_element_client name");
    return 1;
  }

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<beginner_tutorials::GetElement>("get_element");
  beginner_tutorials::GetElement srv;
  srv.request.name = argv[1];
  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Elements: %s, %s", srv.response.result[0].c_str(), srv.response.result[1].c_str());
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service get_element");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

GetElement.h

```
string name
---
string[] result
```

The error that I obtain is the following when I use 'catkin_make':

```
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp: In function ‘bool add(beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Request&, beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response&)’:
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:7:7: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
   res.result = {"table", "chair"};
       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:7:33: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
   res.result = {"table", "chair"};
                                 ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40:0,
                 from /home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:1:
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:8:33: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Request’ has no member named ‘name’
   ROS_INFO("request: x=%s", req.name.c_str());
                                 ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:8:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
   ROS_INFO("request: x=%s", req.name.c_str());
   ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:9:52: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
   ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%s] [%s]", res.result[0].c_str(), res.result[1].c_str());
                                                    ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:9:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
   ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%s] [%s]", res.result[0].c_str(), res.result[1].c_str());
   ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:9:75: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
   ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%s] [%s]", res.result[0].c_str(), res.result[1].c_str());
                                                                           ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:9:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
   ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%s] [%s]", res.result[0].c_str(), res.result[1].c_str());
   ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:17:15: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Request’ has no member named ‘name’
   srv.request.name = argv[1];
               ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40:0,
                 from /home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:1:
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:20:47: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
     ROS_INFO("Elements: %s, %s", srv.response.result[0].c_str(), srv.response.result[1].c_str());
                                               ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:20:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
     ROS_INFO("Elements: %s, %s", srv.response.result[0].c_str(), srv.response.result[1].c_str());
     ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:20:79: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
     ROS_INFO("Elements: %s, %s", srv.response.result[0].c_str(), srv.response.result[1].c_str());
                                                                               ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:342:165: note: in definition of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:375:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_client.cpp:20:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
     ROS_INFO("Elements: %s, %s", srv.response.result[0].c_str(), srv.response.result[1].c_str());
     ^
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/get_element_server.dir/src/get_element_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/get_element_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/get_element_client.dir/src/get_element_client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/get_element_client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Could you help me to learn how to declare the array to make it work?
Thanks to all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239255/return-array-in-service-in-c++/) by [javietos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27458/javietos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-11**:
It looks like most of the error message is missing; please include the full error message from the compiler.

**Comment by [javietos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27458/javietos/) on 2016-07-11**:
Now I include all the error message, if you prefer I can add some images to see it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first errors messages are often the most important. In your errors the important ones seem to be:

```
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:7:7: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Response’ has no member named ‘result’
```

and

```
/home/javier/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/get_element_server.cpp:8:33: error: ‘beginner_tutorials::GetElement::Request’ has no member named ‘name’
```

these errors are repeated several more times in various different contexts within your code.

These errors seem odd, because as listed these fields are present in your service definition.

I would start by checking:

- You list your service definition file as `GetElement.h`; this should be `GetElement.srv`
- You should confirm that C++ headers are being generated from your service definition. They should be automatically generated in the `devel/include/`path/to/package`/GetElement.h` file in your catkin workspace.
- Check that you're including the service definition from the correct package

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [javietos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27458/javietos/) on 2016-07-11**:
Sorry, my fault. I had the names in spanish and at the time of changing them to english I forgot those.
Now the error is much shorter.